# The component is not editable in experience manager in sdl web 8

Tags: experience-manager, web8, sdl-tridion

I am not able to edit component text field in experience manager, Please find below details.
Schema:
[image]

Component Template:
[image]

TBB:
[image]

page Viewsource:
[image]

Site edit:
[image]

Settings:
[image]
Can you please help me what i have missed, Thanks in advance

I am getting following error in browser.
[image]

Comment: Are other parts of your site working in XPM?

Comment: I have enabled xpm for above two fields only and rendering two fields(heading and bodytext)

Comment: You may want to use Chrome Developer Tools (or similar) to see whether the JavaScript that controls XPM is being loaded, or whether another JavaScript error is preventing it from firing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured the Staging **Publishing Target** to use Experience Manager?

This is covered in Step 5 in the following page of the online documentation:
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539

Comment: Yes , we have configured.